# vb.net Execute Batch command At Startup

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Try ' install
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Application.StartupPath, "C:\xx\xx\", True)
    My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).SetValue(Application.ProductName, "C:\xx\xx\ProgramXX.exe")
Catch ioEx As System.IO.IOException
    Console.WriteLine("IO") ' error, program already installed
End Try

Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("settings\internetexplorer.exe") ' build batch command
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
startInfo.Arguments = "settings\settings.<acronym title="JavaScript">js</acronym>"
Process.Start(startInfo) ' this is not started 
Process.Start("C:\xx\xx\ProgramXX.exe")
End Sub
```

It installs properly, and runs on startup. The settings\internetexplorer.exe is not started though.

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on OP's edit:

Okay maybe it is not starting because it cannot find the executable. If you don't mind using the operating system shell to start the process, you can set UseShellExecute = True and then set the working directory

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("internetexplorer.exe")
startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\xxxx\xxx"
```

or much simpler would be

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\xxxx\xxx\internetexplorer.exe")
```

Comment: settings\internetexplorer.exe is not started when the thing is installed. When run for the first time it runs fine. I made a typo, and programXX started fine. it was settings\internetexplorer.exe.